# cx_oracle disable statement echo from console

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I haven't been able to find anything that covers this and I'm not sure it's possible since I can't find anything in the cx_Oracle docs. But, is there a way to turn off the sql statment echo or output? I'm looking for something kind of like the paramiko-expect "display=False" option. Typically, I set the paramiko-expect display option depending on my logging level. That option just seems to be eluding me in cx_Oracle.

This is running Python 2.7/3.7
Oracle version is anything between 12c to 19c
Platform is RH7.9

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean ? can you provide an example of your Python code using cx_Oracle and what exactly you want to turn off ?

Comment: cx_Oracle doesn't echo statements.  It's an API that lets you pass data between Python variables and Oracle Database. It's your application or tool that can display output of those variables or echo what you are typing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what happened, but I put in my logging architecture place of print statements and they stopped. I must have had an unexpected print somewhere in my code that was printing those out. Thanks for the responses... stupid mistake on my part.